# Avoid relative paths when doing an import in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, path

In my vue-cli project, I have the following file structure:

- src

  - components

    - Component1.vue
    - Component2.vue
  - router

    - routes

      - index.js

And I need to import my components in my `router/routes/index.js` in order to handle navigation:

```
import Component1 from '../../components/Component1.vue'
import Component2 from '../../components/Component2.vue'

const routes = [
    { path: '/route1', component: Component1 },
    { path: '/route2', component: Component2 }
]
```

I would like to avoid the full path navigation using `..`, and instead be able to set my `src` folder as a "root" path, in order to do the following:

```
import Component1 from 'src/components/Component1.vue'
import Component2 from 'src/components/Component2.vue'
```

I've read the following article, but I only found solutions regarding `require` statements, not `import`s, and I'd like to keep my homogeneity.

https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520

What are the possible ways of doing this, either using node or an npm library?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@`, `@`- refers your root folder.
For example:

```
'@/components/component1.vue'
```

this is same as your

```
'../../components/Component1.vue'
```

Comment: making function that returns you the component path automatically is also a good practice